# How to write a spec for trap handling on rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, rspec, signals

say I have a class which traps SIGTERM and I want to write a spec to verify that that specific code is ran when SIGTERM is received. What is the proper way of doing it?
I've followed the answer for this topic: [How to test signal handling in RSpec, particularly handling of SIGTERM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571582/how-to-test-signal-handling-in-rspec-particularly-handling-of-sigterm), but rspec is terminated on Process.kill happens.
I've also tried it like this:

```
raise SignalException.new('TERM')
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything (trap is not triggered). Finnaly, I've tried using 'allow' to substitute a method which is called during the spec to raise the signal or call Process.kill like this:

```
allow(<Class>).to receive(<method>).and_raise(SignalException.new('TERM'))
allow(<Class>).to receive(<method>).and_return(Process.kill 'TERM',0)
```

When raising the signal it also doesn't seem to do anything, and calling Process.kill simply ends rspec without a stack trace, just the word 'Terminated').
The trap code is like this:

```
trap('SIGTERM') {
    Rails.logger.error('term')
    @received_sigterm = true
}
```